# Managing seperate ground paths for a driver

Tags: grounding

I'm trying to design an add-on board for a single board computer, similar to an Arduino shield or a rPi hat.  Among other things, the board will control a couple of inductive loads through a ULN2003A IC.

I want to provide a separate connection to ground for the loads, so that the current that drives them will not pass through the rPi.  But the ground pin of the ULN2003A will also be connected to the ground of the rPi board (so that all grounds are connected), thus creating a ground loop.

[image: Schematic]

I'm worried about two things:

1. How should I "route" the current from the loads, so that it will move through the cable, and not through the rPi board.
2. Are there any other issues with the ground loop that I should take into account.

BTW, I feel that these problems will not exist if I use a relay instead of a driver IC, but I prefer to not use relays unless absolutely needed.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the dedicated wire to the 12V supply is sufficiently thicker and/or shorter there shouldn't really be a concern. You can't do much more since you're stuck with the connections between motherboard and daughterboard as is.

I think beginners are too concerned about ground loops. Ground loops aren't a problem until they are a problem. Don't be careless but but you don't need to be obsessive either unless you have long cable runs.